# Consuming slow and synchronous APIs at scale

Tags: java, performance, api, scale, system-design

I am working on a tool that collects a lot of data of various resources of different types, every 15 minutes, from a remote endpoint that consists multiple synchronous APIs, and persist the data in the database. To retrieve data of a single resource, the following APIs have to be called in sequence:

1. Retrieve resource IDs by pages. Each page contains 25 IDs
2. For each ID retrieved in a page, retrieve the state of the resource
3. For each ID retrieved in a page, retrieve the state of its dependencies - separate API call for each dependency.

I found one particular resource API (say for resource type **X**) is pretty slow and this slows down all the calls involved in Step 1 to 3. Since a few resources are dependent on one another, each resource type is retrieved, processed and persisted in a single separate stage of its own, and all such stages are chained in sequence. The stage which is processing resource type **X** consumes significantly more time for large volumes of data and causes the whole chain to be delayed.

I am looking for approaches when dealing with consuming slow and synchronous APIs, at scale, that become potentially blocking in cases like mine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very general and is around some concepts of system design.

Try reading / R&D about these:

- Decoupling business logic with Async calls (Kafka / SQS / ....)
- Frameworks such as [Akka](https://akka.io/)